# Transcribing with Custom Language Model (python API) in AWS - ModelSettings error

Tags: python, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to transcribe speech using Custom Language Model using Python API. I followed the example script available on the AWS webpage. However, it throws the following error, saying it doesn't support the 'LanguageModelName' parameter under ModelSettings.

ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ModelSettings", must be one of: TranscriptionJobName, LanguageCode, MediaSampleRateHertz, MediaFormat, Media, OutputBucketName, Settings

```
transcribe.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName = job_name,
    Media = {'MediaFileUri': job_uri},
    MediaFormat = 'media-format',
    LanguageCode = 'language-code',
ModelSettings = {
    'LanguageModelName': 'language-model-name'
    }
)
```

Could anyone please help regarding this?

Comment: I had posted the same question in the Amazon developers portal. After few days without any change in the code, it suddenly started working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be wrong on your request in particular, but I tried the following with no issue:

```
transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe', region_name='us-west-2')
transcribe.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName = 'test-so-clm-1',
    Media = {'MediaFileUri': 's3://bucket/folder/audio.wav'},
    MediaFormat = 'wav',
    LanguageCode = 'en-US',
    ModelSettings = {
    'LanguageModelName': 'test1'
    }
)
```

In my case my Custom Language Model is named `test1`. Make sure your CLM name matches. Maybe the error is being raised like something is wrong with the "keys" under `ModelSettings` but in reality it's the actual value that's wrong. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I had posted the same question in the Amazon developers portal. After few days without any change in the code, it suddenly started working.